# How to use timeout with deffered result in spring mvc?

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-boot, timeout, servlet-3.0

I have found following article: Spring MVC 3.2 Preview: Introducing Servlet 3, Async Support

example:

```
@RequestMapping("/quotes")
@ResponseBody
public DeferredResult<String> quotes() {
  DeferredResult<String> deferredResult = new DeferredResult<String>();
  // Add deferredResult to a Queue or a Map...
  return deferredResult;
}


// In some other thread...    <-- important phrase
 deferredResult.setResult(data);
// Remove deferredResult from the Queue or Map
```

But I need in case if result was not set within 1 minute - error resul should be returned.

How to change this example according my requirement ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DeferredResult has constructor which can be used for your requirement.

```
 /**
         * Create a DeferredResult with a timeout value and a default result to use
         * in case of timeout.
         * @param timeout timeout value in milliseconds (ignored if {@code null})
         * @param timeoutResult the result to use
         */
        public DeferredResult(Long timeout, Object timeoutResult) {
            this.timeoutResult = timeoutResult;
            this.timeout = timeout;
        }
```